# Change RTE Default font size not reflecting on RTE html editor

Tags: richtext-editor

I changed RTE default font size by changing `Website\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Editor.css` :

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

This is working fine for the RTE `Design` tab but not for the `HTML` tab.

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Updates you made will work fine for the RTE design but it will not work with the HTML tab because if you will see the HTML part of it, you will see RTE design has its own iFrame with styles in it and HTML tab is a simple text area. Sitecore uses these UI controls from Telerik and if you want to apply the style on HTML tab as well then the easy way is to edit the `EditorPage.aspx` file under `sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor`. you can open this file in any text editor and add the style in it as below -

```
.RadForm_Default.rfdTextarea textarea.reTextArea {
      font-size:20px;
      }
```

make sure to maintain the hierarchy for this. `reTextArea` is class of the textarea tag in the editor. for refrence see below image - [image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. I applied css in EditorPage.aspx, but no change reflecting. I checked that the textarea is taking inline css. <textarea style="font:normal 11px Tahoma;color: #000080;border:0px;height:100%;width:100%;resize:none;"></textarea>. Can i change the inline css or js file where the style is being loaded from ? Thank inadvance.

Comment: As I mentioned already this is a telerik UI but if the css is not working then try '! Important' properly

Comment: @user6016 can you please add some screenshots? because I have tested this on 9.2 and it is working fine.

Comment: will changing my rich text editor body { font-size: 20px;} effect the other font size as well, I can see that other font get up by 2 font size. Not sure what I am doing wrong as my only requirement was to make 3 font-size default selected in site rich text box editor.